# Getting linked documents in single lookup query in Elastic Search

Tags: python, elasticsearch, nosql

To provide some context : 
I want to write a bulk update query(possibly affecting 0.5 - 1M docs). The update would be in the `aspects` field (shown below) which are mostly duplicated. 
My thinking was if I normalised it into another entity (`aspect_label`), the amount of docs updated would be reduced drastically (say 500-1000 max).

**Query :** I want to find out if there is a way to get linked documents via id in Elastic Search.

Eg. if I have documents in index `my_db` according to the mapping below.

Just to point out : `processed_reviews` is a child of `aspect_label`

```
{
   "my_db":{
      "mappings":{
         "processed_reviews":{
            "_all":{
               "enabled":false
            },
            "_parent":{
               "type":"aspect_label"
            },
            "_routing":{
               "required":true
            },
            "properties":{
               "data":{
                  "properties":{
                     "insights":{
                        "type":"nested",
                        "properties":{
                           "aspects":{
                              "type":"nested",
                              "properties":{
                                 "aspect_label_id":{
                                    "type":"keyword"
                                 },
                                 "aspect_term_frequency":{
                                    "type":"long"
                                 }
                              }
                           }
                        }
                     },
                     "preprocessed_text":{
                        "type":"text"
                     },
                     "preprocessed_title":{
                        "type":"text"
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

And another entity `aspect_label` :

```
{
  "my_db": {
    "mappings": {
      "aspect_label": {
        "_all": {
          "enabled": false
        },
        "properties": {
          "aspect": {
            "type": "keyword"
          },
          "aspect_label_new": {
            "type": "keyword"
          },
          "aspect_label_old": {
            "type": "text"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now, I want to write a search query on the `processed_reviews` type such that the `aspect_label_id` entity is replaced with the the value of `aspect_label_new` in the doc or the entire doc in `aspect_label` matching the id.

```
{
    "_index":"my_db",
    "_type":"processed_reviews",
    "_id":"191b3bff-4915-4404-a05a-10e6bd2b19d4",
    "_score":1,
    "_routing":"5",
    "_parent":"5",
    "_source":{
        "data":{
            "preprocessed_text":"Good product I really like so comfortable and so light wait and looks good",
            "preprocessed_title":"Good choice",
            "insights":[
                {
                    "aspects":[
                        {
                            "aspect_label":"color",
                            "aspect_term_frequency":1
                        }
                    ]
                    }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Also, if there is a better way to approach this problem/ something wrong with my approach or if this is possible or not. Please inform me of the same as well.

Comment: to have a get bulk query, you should use a mget query in python http://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html?highlight=mget#elasticsearch.Elasticsearch.mget , to have a bulk import you could use a parallel_bulk query http://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/helpers.html#elasticsearch.helpers.parallel_bulk If you will provide some code, we could help you better

Comment: Hi, 
this is not what I am looking for. 

I explained my use case.

I am stuck with the approach to write the query itself. 

I have considered application level joins but that just seemed ugly.

Comment: Also for me, explain how python and elasticsearch works are not what I'm looking for. If you have a question I can help you, as I do every day here. But I can't replace you on make the better choice. I haven't seen your data, I don't know the volume of your data, I don't know if your application is for real time usage or only for analysis. So be understable. Duplicates a field for join is the better choice for SQL DB, most of the times it has no sense on ES, because the join operator has no sense in non relational data. NoSQL DB are born for avoid join, you know? Change your mind, please